# How to make firefox 4 open home page when opening a new tab

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

In previous versions of firefox when you opened a new tab it would load your homepage in that tab if you had "open homepage" set in your options. In firefox 4 it only seems to open the homepage when the browser is first started, when a new tab is opened it just shows a blank screen.

Is there anyway to make firefox 4 open your homepage when a new tab is opened?

Comment: I think the add-on is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/) that allows this.  Chrome allows this out of the box... I'm surprised that Firefox does not. Did you check in the options? They may have moved it...

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is apparently by design: there are at least [two](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=269664) [bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187573) filed about how new tabs (and windows) work that have been filed WON'T FIX.

However, there are two bits of good news for you. One is that there is a similar feature [in the works](https://wiki.mozilla.org/New_Tab_page). Hopefully one of the options they will present is the ability to open your home page.

The other is that there is a workaround that does not involve installing add-ons: you can open a new tab (or tabs) to your home page(s) by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-clicking or middle-clicking the Home icon.